# Do we "have" to use MsiExec to install a Wix patch?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

We normally install Wix patches (xxx.msp) by double-clicking them. But I see at various places over the internet that we should use the MsiExec utility. For e.g. `msiexec /update patch.msp REINSTALL=ALL`

Is there any downside in not using the MsiExec utility?

Comment: When you double click, it effectively runs `msiexec /p patch.msp`, but I can't find documentation on `/p`

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no downside. Effectively, double-clicking runs `msiexec /p patch.msp`.

If your patch updates only the versioned files, EXE and DLL, and work correctly without adding `REINSTALL=ALL`, then it's great!

The point of using `msiexec` explicitly is to add `REINSTALL=ALL` property. It make the installer to re-install all the files. This is usually added to fix the problems where some files do not get updated when the patch is installed directly by double-clicking.